# php dynamic POST[] values

Tags: php, sql, dynamic

I have this sql statement that gets user input from a form and stores the values in the database

```
foreach ($_POST["name"] as $key => $name) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_table(name,price) VALUES ('".$name."','".$_POST["price"]."')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

In my database, I get the correct name value but on the price field I get an array. Is there a way to get the value of the `POST['price']`?

Comment: Please show us your HTML for your form.

Comment: `$_POST["price"][$key]` I suppose. And start using prepared statements, you queries are vulnerable to SQL-injections.

Comment: @u_mulder you are correct

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop through the price too

If you are getting values from a single form do you need to pass them individually

you can create an array like this

```
$form_field = array($_POST["name"], $_POST["price"]);
foreach($form_field as $field => $value){
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table(name,price) VALUES ('".$value[0]."','".$value[1]."')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);

}
```

Try this out and see